# Create unique doubles and triplets from collection

Tags: c#, .net, collections

I have a Collection (`List`) of items (`String`). Number of items in this collection will always be between 0 to 9.

I need to create all combinations of pairs and triples from this collection.
Position of item in double or triplet does not matter. So `{1,2}` is equal to `{2,1}`.

How can i achieve this? Maybe there is some nice way to do this via LINQ?

Comment: take a look at here http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Combinatorics.aspx

Comment: no it is not a homework. It is used for sudoku solving method called hidden subsets. I do need to Find all combinations of Possibilities (doubles, triples) and test if these doubles/triples are exactly only in two or three cells in given row/cell/square. If it is i have found hidden pair/triplet and can reduce number off possibilities in  these cells.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the code below I generate all unique doubles and triplets using linq. I use the fact that strings have a total ordering.

This generates all doubles:

```
string[] items = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J" };

var combinations = 
    from a in items
    from b in items
    where a.CompareTo(b) < 0
    orderby a, b
    select new { A = a, B = b };

foreach(var pair in combinations)
    Console.WriteLine("({0}, {1})", pair.A, pair.B);
```

This generates all triplets:

```
string[] items = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J" };

var combinations = 
    from a in items
    from b in items
    from c in items
    where a.CompareTo(b) < 0 && b.CompareTo(c) < 0
    orderby a, b, c
    select new { A = a, B = b, C = c };

foreach(var triplet in combinations)
    Console.WriteLine("({0}, {1}, {2})", triplet.A, triplet.B, triplet.C);
```

**Update:**  There is a generic solution to create all unique subsets of a specific length, and still use linq. However, you need a returntype that can contain the subset. I created a simple class `LinkedNode`, because to me this feels most natural in combination with linq:

```
void Main()
{
    string[] items = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J" };

    foreach(var combination in CreateCombinations(items, 5))
        Console.WriteLine("({0})", combination.ToString());
}

private static IEnumerable<LinkedNode> CreateCombinations(string[] items, int length)
{
    if(length == 1)
        return items.Select(item => new LinkedNode { Value = item, Next = null });

    return from a in items 
        from b in CreateCombinations(items, length - 1) 
        where a.CompareTo(b.Value) < 0
        orderby a, b.Value
        select new LinkedNode<T> { Value = a, Next = b };
}

public class LinkedNode
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public LinkedNode Next { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return (this.Next == null) ? Value : Value + ", " + Next.ToString();
    }
}
```

It should be easy to implement `IEnumerable<string>` on the class `LinkedNode`, or otherwise convert the LinkedNodes to a `List<string>` or `HashSet<string>`. Note that you can remove the line `orderby a, b.Value` if the order is not important.

Comment: Thank you, it looks good, but - is there a way to write this query universally to work with any number of n-tuplets (i hope it is correct term in english)? I mean - method where i provide integer N and depending on N i get result - N=2: doubles, N=3:triplets, N=4: Quads.

Comment: @VojtechRuzicka that should be a different question.

Comment: Yes, there is, but what kind of objects do you expect to get?

Comment: Nice one Elian. @VojtechRuzicka: n-tuple is the [correct term](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple).

Comment: @Hogan Ok, lets exclude quads and higher, but i think if we leave doubles and triplets, it is not off topic to ask if there is universal solution both for doubles and triplets and not two methods which have a lot of code common. No offense though and answer accepted, because it solves my problem. just pointing out possible improvement.

Comment: @Elian I know a number N of n-tuplets expected (eg 2,3) and want receive collection of strings (i think any IEnumerable should be fine). so i provide collection of source strings and N and i want to receive Collection of collections where each collections contains this n-tuple. For example i provide n=2 and source collection {1,2,3} and i receive collection containig collections of {1,2},{1,3},{2,3}

Comment: @Elian Thank you very much, apreciate that.